# Form wide onclick event: every input field has the exact same on click event

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I've got this Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>
        <input type="Text" formControlName="input1">
    </label>
    ...
    <label>
        <input type="Text" formControlName="input20">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and i was wondering wether it is possible to include a shared behaviour between each input.

Specifically, im trying to display two radio buttons `<input type="radio" value="yes">Yes<br><input type="radio" value="no">No<br>` right below the input, in which is currently focused. Then the selected value needs to be somehow included with the text input value onsubmit.

In my components typescript i have something like this:

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    input1: [''],
    ...
    input20: [''],
});

onSubmit(){ //super hardcode i know e.e
    let output: string = '';
    output += this.myForm.get('input1').value;
    ...
    output += ", " + this.myForm.get('input20').value;
    //this would be used by some service then, and wouldnt be a long string
    //but rather an object or something
    console.log(output); 
}
```

Comment: You want to show selected value in input field when you submit?

Comment: No, i want to submit it in pairs. Textfield value + corresponding checkbox value

Comment: what about using a ArrayForm of formGroup ?

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll. It will give you NodeList of DOM elements

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

Then you would loop through each element

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs .length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        //Your logic here
    });
}
```

Comment: sure this is not the Angular way